# How to compute the cross point between an ellipse and a straight line?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Please let me know how to compute the possible cross points between an ellipse and a straight line.
In details , I know the basic properties of the two shapes.
So if the ellipse had its center at the origin and its axes were same as the XY axes then I could compute the cross points.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just solve the system of equations
$$
\eqalign{&{x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1\cr &y=mx+c}
$$
using the substitution method.

I assume by ''cross point'' you mean ``intersection point''.